# How to split and update list with multiple look up values

Tags: excel, split, vba

Currently i am reading rows from the excel sheet and updating a SharePoint list. Some of them are look up columns.

Now say for example one row from excel is:

```
Distribution A+;#253;#Distribution FACTS;#256;#Distribution SX.e;#257
```

Now my requirement is i need to split them like:

```
ID;#Value;#ID;#Value;#ID;#Value
```

and then update in the list.

**Code**

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(listTable.Rows[iRow][‌​23]))) {   
} else { 
newlistitem["Product"] = Convert.ToString(listTable.Rows[iRow][23]); 
}
```

Comment: Right now my code is

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(listTable.Rows[iRow][23])))
{
}
else
{
  newlistitem["Product"] = Convert.ToString(listTable.Rows[iRow][23]);
}